# Nested axios calls updating react state before all requests have finished

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, asynchronous, axios

I am doing some nested axios calls as in order to create the object i want i need to fire off a couple of different API's. My problem is that when i call setState, the state will start updating before all requests have finished so my table will populate entry by entry which does not look nice. 
here is my code:

```js
fetchServices = async ()=> {
  this.setState({isLoading: true})
  await axios({
    method: 'get',
    url :getApiUrl(),
    headers:{
      "Accept": "application/json"
    }
  })
  .then( async response => {
      let Data: any[] = []
      response.data.Message.forEach(async (e: any) => {
      await axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: getApiUrl() + "/" + e.organisationErn + "/services",
        headers:{
          "Accept": "application/json"
        }
      }).then( async response => {
        console.log(response)
        if(response.data.Message !== "No services found"){
          response.data.Message.forEach(async(e:any)=>{
            let orgName = await axios({
              method: 'get',
              url: getApiUrl() + "/" +  e.organisationErn, 
              headers:{"Accept": "application/json"}})
                .then(response => {return response.data.Message.organisationName});
            let entry =  {
              servicename: { text: e.serviceName },
              servicetype: { text: e.serviceTypeDescription },
              organisation: { text: orgName },
            };
            Data.push(entry);
            this.setState({ tableData: Data });
          })
        };
      });
    });
    setTimeout(()=>{this.setState({isLoading: false})}, 100) 
  }).catch(error => {
    alert(error)
  });
};
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! :) Something quick I'd like to point out is that the reason async/await is helpful is because it helps you not worry about appending then and catch statements everywhere. So you could simply await a promise, and move on to the next line without proceeding with ".then(...)". Apart from this, Eldar's suggestion to use Promise.all() is quite logical. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well you are pushing your data one by one. You can use `Promise.all` to await all requests complete then populate your state.

```
 if (response.data.Message !== "No services found") {
             const promises = response.data.Message.map((e: any) => {
               axios({
                   method: 'get',
                   url: getApiUrl() + "/" + e.organisationErn,
                   headers: {
                     "Accept": "application/json"
                   }
                 })
                 .then(response => {
                   return response.data.Message.organisationName
                 })
                 .then(org => {
                   return {
                     servicename: {
                       text: e.serviceName
                     },
                     servicetype: {
                       text: e.serviceTypeDescription
                     },
                     organisation: {
                       text: org
                     },
                   };
                 });  

             });

              const Data = await Promise.all([...promises]);
          this.setState({ tableData: Data });
```

BTW there may be some parentheses errors.

Comment: Thanks Eldar. This didnt quite work tho, because on the second .then statement e.serviceName, etc are undefined in that scope i think. 
yes in my example code one of the parentheses was missing at the very end.. :/

Comment: @JustasDaugintis actually `e` must be defined in the context because all `then`s are inside the `response.data.Message.map` loop

Answer (score 0):

I think its better to get the result from each axios request and use it at the end, instead of using `then`

like

```
const result1= await axios.get(...);
const result1= await axios.get(...);
const result1= await axios.get(...);
setState({ tableData: Data });
```

you can also refer https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-use-async-await-with-axios-in-react-e07daac2905f